# RxJS scan and filter vs bufferCount issue

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I encountered a problem when playing with ngrx effect and rxjs. I am using two versions of effect (simplified for purpose of this question):

Version 1:

```
public effect$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(
        actions.successAction1,
        actions.successAction2,
        ...
      ),
      scan((actionCount, typedAction) => actionCount + 1, 0),
      filter((actionCount) => actionCount === 2), // If more actions, then this value is different
      map((actionCount) => actions.finalAction())
    )
  );
```

Version 2:

```
public effect$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(
        actions.successAction1, 
        actions.successAction2
        ...
      ),
      bufferCount(2), // If more actions, then this value is different
      switchMap(() => actions.finalAction())
    )
  );
```

I really do not understand why first version is working, and second is not. I expect the "finalAction" to be dispatched after 2 actions (succcessAction1 and successAction2) are dispatched.

Comment: I don't think you should be using `switchMap(() => actions.finalAction())` in the second example and use just `map()`.

Comment: +1 @martin's comment. `map()` operator is meant for transformations and it just returns the value. `switchMap()` operator however is a higher order mapping operator meant to switch from one observable to another. It _must_ return an observable. Internally it subscribes to the inner observable and emits it's emissions forward. If your `actions.finalAction()` doesn't return an observable, the `switchMap()` operator usage here is incorrect. And if it does return an observable, and you wish to _not_ subscribe to it and return it as an observable forward, then it should be the `map` operator.

Comment: Unless it's an array you wish to explode an emit as individual values

Comment: @Marek can you post a minimal stackblitz repro (no ngrx please, only rxjs to mimic the effect) but I don't see why that wouldn't work. If you provide a minimal repro and it doesn't work, I'm happy to take a look

Comment: @maxime1992 You're right, but if the first example works as expected then it probably returns just an action object.

Answer (score -3):

In the first version, you are using the scan operator to accumulate a count of actions, and then using the filter operator to check if the count is equal to 2 before dispatching the final action. This works as expected because the scan operator maintains state and continuously updates the count with each incoming action.

In the second version, you are using the bufferCount(2) operator, which buffers the last 2 emitted values and emits an array containing those values. However, you are missing a key point in the second version: the bufferCount(2) operator does not emit an array for every two actions. Instead, it emits an array after every two values emitted by the source observable.

To achieve the desired behavior in the second version, you need to modify it as follows:

```js
public effect$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(
        actions.successAction1, 
        actions.successAction2
        ...
      ),
      bufferCount(2),
      filter(actionsArray => actionsArray.length === 2), // Check if the array contains two actions
      switchMap(() => actions.finalAction())
    )
);
```

By adding the filter(actionsArray => actionsArray.length === 2) after bufferCount(2), you ensure that the final action is only dispatched when there are exactly two actions in the buffered array. This should now behave similarly to the first version with scan and filter.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy